# Scenario vs. Scenario Outline

Tags: php, behat

**Background:**

I'm currently writing behat tests (Mink/Selenium) for a Symfony2 webpage. I have a good deal of examples to go by, and actually writing them should be no problem. The step definitions are already written.

However, in the examples, they some times define a `Scenario:` and some times a `Scenario Outline:`

**Question:**

What is the difference between these two ways of defining a test?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [the official guide](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/1.gherkin.html#scenario-outlines):

> Copying and pasting scenarios to use different values can quickly become tedious and repetitive:
>
> ```
> Scenario: Eat 5 out of 12
>   Given there are 12 cucumbers
>   When I eat 5 cucumbers
>   Then I should have 7 cucumbers
>
> Scenario: Eat 5 out of 20
>   Given there are 20 cucumbers
>   When I eat 5 cucumbers
>   Then I should have 15 cucumbers
> ```
>
> Scenario Outlines allow us to more concisely express these examples through the use of a template with placeholders
>
> ```
> Scenario Outline: Eating
>   Given there are <start> cucumbers
>   When I eat <eat> cucumbers
>   Then I should have <left> cucumbers
>
>   Examples:
>     | start | eat | left |
>     |  12   |  5  |  7   |
>     |  20   |  5  |  15  |
> ```
>
> The Scenario Outline steps provide a template which is never directly run. A Scenario Outline is run once for each row in the Examples section beneath it (except for the first header row).

More in the [Writing Features](https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/writing_scenarios.html) guide.

Comment: Do i have to have the simple `Scenario` when i have `Scenario Outlet`?

Comment: @Salman no. `Scenario Outline` is simply a scenario with a set of examples. Whenever you need to use the `Examples` section, you need to use the `Scenario Outline` instead of a `Scenario`. The difference is that a `Scenario`  will be executed once while `Scenario Outline` is executed for each example from the table.

Comment: A new link on guide for writing scenarios can be found at: https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/writing_scenarios.html

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to autodetect this. This is an unnecessary source of mistakes. From what I can see, cucumber.js correctly handles examples, even if you write only 'Scenario'

Comment: @PostSelf If this is something that the original Cucumber supports, I'm sure Behat maintainers would accept your pull request to support it in their project as well.

Answer (score -1):

Scenario is what it is.

Scenario outline uses placeholders for faster testing.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "faster testing"? Also, the given link is broken